# Bulk Loading large dataframe into Astra DB

Tags: python, cassandra, datastax, datastax-astra

I'm trying to load my dataframe into AstraDB but its taking forever to load.. i was wondering if there's a faster method to do it via python?

```
import cassandra 
from cassandra.cluster import Cluster
from cassandra.auth import PlainTextAuthProvider
import pandas as pd

cloud_config= {
        'secure_connect_bundle': 'secure-connect-capstone-project.zip'
}
auth_provider = PlainTextAuthProvider(user,pass)
cluster = Cluster(cloud=cloud_config, auth_provider=auth_provider)
#connect to keyspace_name
session = cluster.connect('iac689')

query = """insert into data_2 (truck_id, active, reading_id, start_mileage, start_time, truck_name, type)
values (%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s)"""
for i in df.values:
    session.execute(query, [i[0],i[1],i[2],i[3],i[4],i[5],i[6]])
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you really need to do this via Python, then you can speedup code by:

- Using [prepared queries](https://docs.datastax.com/en/developer/python-driver/3.25/getting_started/#prepared-statement) - call `session.prepare` on your query string, and use it in `session.execute`.
- Use asynchronous API (`execute_async`) instead of synchronous (`execute`).  But you need to track how many in-flight queries you have, etc. to avoid getting errors.

Really, I would recommend to not re-invent the wheel, but dump data as CSV or JSON file, and use [DSBulk](https://docs.datastax.com/en/dsbulk/doc/index.html) to load data into Cassandra/Astra - this tool is heavily optimized for loading/unloading data from Cassandra/Astra.